# Facebook Scrabble and flash

Tags: flash

I'm running Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit. I can't get Scrabble Facebook to run in Firefox. I installed flash-aid and no joy.

Help?

Comment: Do other Flash sites work? Youtube?

Comment: Yes, YouTube worked fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorry, I clicked on the flash-aid icon and ran the wizard and it cleaned everything up and now Facebook Scrabble seems to be working fine.

Whew! Life without Scrabble simply isn't worth living.